# javascript looping over data and recreating a data structure

Tags: javascript

If I have data like this:

```
{
"zone_temps" : {
   "VAV1": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
   "VAV2": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
   "VAV3": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
   "VAV4": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
   "VAV5": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
   "VAV6": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
   "VAV7": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",   
   "VAV8": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",   
   "VAV9": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",   
   "VAV10": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1"}
}
```

Could someone give me a tip what a javascript function would look like looping over the data and recreating the data structure with same keys but the values would be in integer made from `math.random()`

Hopefully that makes sense, looking for a final output like this:

```
{
"zone_temps" : {
   "VAV1": "66",
   "VAV2": "88",
   "VAV3": "55",
   "VAV4": "66",
   "VAV5": "77",
   "VAV6": "67",
   "VAV7": "79",   
   "VAV8": "87",   
   "VAV9": "75",   
   "VAV10": "71"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The English in the question is almost the answer in JS:  Loop over the keys (`map()`) producing key-value pairs with random (`Math.random()`) values. `Object.fromEntries()` combines those pairs into a new object

```js
const temps = {
  "VAV1": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
  "VAV2": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
  "VAV3": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
  "VAV4": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
  "VAV5": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
  "VAV6": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
  "VAV7": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
  "VAV8": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1",
  "VAV9": "read 12345:2 analogInput 2",
  "VAV10": "read 12345:2 analogInput 1"
}

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(temps).map(key => {
  return [ key, Math.round(Math.random()*100) ]
}))

console.log(result)
```